# How to generate scheme in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I trying to add postgresql database into my spring boot project.
This is my maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I added User entity and UsersRepository and trying to test it.

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(123);
    user.setCity("ABC");

    usersRepository.save(user);
```

But I get an error:

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist`

Scheme wasn't created. What do I need to generate the scheme?

Comment: try `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create`

Comment: @sidgate I'm already did it